# ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm new to Android development, and I'm having trouble with a simple
Hello World app..
It worked yesterday with the emulator, on a virtual device with Android
1.5

When I run the app a day after, it's stuck at the android startup
screen continuously outputting the following:

```
[2012-02-17 23:40:03 - HelloWorldAndroid] Starting activity
com.mathias.HelloWorldAndroidActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-02-17 23:40:05 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't
dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined
[2012-02-17 23:40:05 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: Can't
dispatch DDM chunk 4d505251: no handler defined
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] Device not ready. Waiting 3
seconds before next attempt.
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: INTENT is
described with:
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [-a
<ACTION>] [-d <DATA_URI>] [-t <MIME_TYPE>]
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [-c
<CATEGORY> [-c <CATEGORY>] ...]
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [-e|--es
<EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [--ez
<EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...]
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [-e|--ei
<EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...]
[2012-02-17 23:40:06 - HelloWorldAndroid] ActivityManager: [-n
<COMPONENT>] [-f <FLAGS>] [<URI>]
```

I've searched google and found several people with the same problem, but I was unable to find a solution.

I'm running Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1

Looking forward to more app development, when I get this working :-)
Thanks in advance!

/Mathias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually see "Can't dispatch DDM chunk" when there are issues with the SDK installation. Make sure that you do not have two different copies of the Android SDK and are mixing and matching them (e.g., you are using one SDK copy with Eclipse and a different SDK copy from the command line at the same time).

Comment: Thanks, I also noticed that a new project with the excact same source code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have read that it is a message that means that your app requirements and AVD are slightly incompatible. For example, if you have Android 3.2 installed for ad purposes, and you test the app on a Android 2.1 emulator, you will get this message.

And one important thing is that, you've to provide minSDKVersion and targetVersion in manifest file.